# what is the fastest way to read strings contating int to an array

Tags: c++, optimization

I have a file that contains numbers as string such as follow:

```
1 2
10 22
123 0
125 87
```

I want to read the into a two dim array so I have

```
lut[0]={1,2};
lut[1]={10,22};
lut[2]={123,0};
lut[3]={125,87};
```

What is the fastest way to do this in c++

Comment: You probally go for std::vector<int> and in you case you might go for `std::vector <std::vector<int> >`

Comment: @hetepeperfan How to convert string to int?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream

Comment: @hetepeperfan Thanks. Can you provide a bit of code? I am not a c++ programmer but a c# and hence I am a bit lost in c++ :(

Comment: Donald Knuth: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming." Make sure you understand C++ first then start to optimalize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any file input/output is slow in comparison with processor calculations. So you can parse file with any way you want. Run time will be close to time of the file input operation.

**Code sample**

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/XhHNzv)

```
#include <fstream>

const static int N = 1000;

int main()
{
    int lut[N][2];

    std::ifstream f("input_file.txt");

    int index = 0;
    while(!f.eof())
    {
        int l1 = 0;
        int l2 = 0;

        f >> l1 >> l2;

        lut[index][0] = l1;
        lut[index][1] = l2;
        ++index;

        if (index == N)
            break; // WARN
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks. Can I read all of the file in one go and then  parse it? Is it faster? If yes, how?

Comment: @mans: You can memory map the entire file, but then you have to do the parsing yourself, which is insane compared to how easy the readily available C++ (or even C stdio) functionality is. Unless you have several millions of values, you will not notice a difference anyway.

Comment: Thanks. This is working with one problem. What would happen if the line is empty for example when some input lines are empty? I want to set values for an empty line to {-1,-1}

Comment: If there will be less then N lines, '!f.eof()' become false and cycle will end. So you have count of actually processed lines in 'index' variable.

Comment: @inkooboo I can read all lines, but some lines are empty in input file for example maybe line 5 is empty, but line 6 and 7 have data and line 8 is empty. How can I detect that?

Comment: @mans You need to read whole line using std::getline. Check that it is not empty. If not then parse it manually. Use search to know how to perform this actions in C++.